# Problems with Bootstrap 3 Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, azure

I am using Bootstrap Carousel 3 in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 CTP completely out of the box.  I am publishing to an Azure web app.  The carousel is not working consistently across all browsers.  I looks fine in Edge and shows the left and right chevrons.  The behavior is the same in Firefox.  In Chrome, the right and left chevrons do not show and the carousel is getting stuck on the last slide.  IE 11 is exhibiting this behavior.

The carousel in Chrome looks OK in my dev environment.  I thought it might be a matter of the prod, staging environment settings, so I made these exactly the same as dev and published.  This did not solve the problem, however.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the corresponding source so people can better answer your question. Without this, it would prove rather difficult to see what you're doing and where a potential issue is.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix the problem.  It was with the environmental settings.  I thought I had made these the same in prod, staging as in dev, but had not.  I am using bootstrap 3.3.5 but in staging, prod I had the href as "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
when it needed to be
"https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"